# why does rails create assets with specific extensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using rails 4. This question is out of curiosity. When we create a rails application, rails add 'application.css' under stylesheets and 'application.js' under javascripts. But when we create a controller, rails add files with extensions 'css.scss' and 'js.coffee'. Why is it so?

Answer (score -1):

`.scss` is the extension used by [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), a CSS preprocessor.

`.coffee` is the extension used by [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), a Ruby-like language that compiles to JavaScript.

The two are very popular in the Ruby/Rails universe, but you can switch them out for plain CSS or JS, or (my personal favorite) [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: so why doesnt rails create application.css.scss rather than application.css? css.scss comes from scss-rails gem and js.coffee from  coffee-rails gem

Comment: I don't think rails is stupid to do that. There has to be some meaning.